# How can I get focus on hyperlink or button on focus of textfield using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input text field and a button.

How can I get focus on button with id-'searchref'on focus of my input text field using JQuery?

Comment: Can 2 elements have `focus` at a same time ? It will be BAD for UX..

Comment: i have a text field inside which there is a search butoon, so when i put my cursor inside text field and hit enter, so it should give me search result but currently it is submitting the whole form.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [focus()](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) method to bind an event handler to the "focus" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

```
$('selector').focus(function(){
    // your code goes here
})
```

Comment: $("#txtSearch").focus(function () {

  
        $("#searchref").focus();
    }); where txtSearch is id of input text field and searchref is id of button and this is not working